# Sobre verificação de tamanho

Tags: javascript, html

Já achei diversas explicações sobre, mas nenhuma conclusiva. É possível determinar o tamanho (em bytes) de uma imagem após ela ser carregada e utilizando Javascript? Aparentemente a segurança dos navegadores impediria-nos de puxar essa informação via XMLHttpRequest dando erro na cross domain request, existe uma maneira de transpassar essa limitação?

Comment: Se a imagem não estiver no seu domínio é pra dar "problema" de *cross domain request* mesmo. Se não fosse assim, teríamos sérios problemas de segurança - mas note que alguns servidores permitem a requisição inter-domínios em alguns casos. Se a imagem estiver no mesmo domínio então é tranquilo acessar a imagem. Espero que, para esse caso, você obtenha uma resposta boa aqui ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Recuperar dados de imagens no disco local:**

Para navegadores que suportem HTML5/CSS3, é possível de acordo com o código a seguir:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL; // alternate use

function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function(_file) {
        image.src    = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function() {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name,
                s = ~~(file.size/1024) +'KB';
            $('#uploadPreview').append('<img src="'+ this.src +'"> '+w+'x'+h+' '+s+' '+t+' '+n+'<br>');
        };
        image.onerror= function() {
            alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
        };      
    };

}
$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if(this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if(F && F[0]) for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) readImage( F[i] );
});
```

A linha `s = ~~(file.size/1024) +'KB';` lhe dá o tamanho em bytes.

Veja esse [link](http://jsbin.com/oTAtIpA/3/edit) para um demo.

Usei como referência [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload) do stackoverflow em inglês.

**Recuperar dados de imagem carregada a partir de uma URL:**

A seguir é mostrado um exemplo simples que mostra propriedades de uma imagem recuperada de uma URL, sem mostrar o tamanho:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

Essa resposta também é retirada de um [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript) do stackoverflow em inglês.

Segundo esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253266/how-to-have-jquery-get-image-size-in-bytes-not-image-dimensions) do stackoverflow em inglês, não é possível recuperar o tamanho de uma imagem na página, via javascript, apenas via server side. Veja que a resposta foi marcada como correta.

Comment: Esse método só é possível localmente, eu precisava de uma maneira de calcular o peso com a imagem já carregada na página, ou a partir da url da mesma.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Veja que não é possível calcular o tamanho localmente. Caso isso tenha respondido a sua pergunta, por favor, a marque como tal "ticando" o check verde a esquerda da questão. Por favor, de um upvote na questão caso já não o tenha feito. Obrigado :)